# v-i characteristic

Tags: thevenin, norton

I have no idea how to tackle this one. can anyone help? 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The voltage at i=0 represents the open circuit voltage, which is your equivalent Thevenin voltage (Veq = 1V). The current at v=0 (short circuit current, i = 2 amps) is equal to the Veq over the equivalent thevenin resistance Req, i.e. your Req = Veq/i= 1V/2amps, which is also equal to the Norton equivalent resistance.
The Norton equivalent current source is the short circuit current, i.e. 2 amps.